# Abaqus XFEM crack propagation

Tags: abaqus

I'm trying to run a simulation about crack progation using XFEM.
In particular, I have a 2D case where I'm representing a composite material composed of matrix plus a single fiber. I would like to underline the crack propagation path derived by the difference in toughness between the matrix and the composite.

[image]

I'm attaching a figure to better clarify the starting point.

The problem is that, before running the simulation, Abaqus displays the warning "ABAQUS CRACK DOMAIN CONTAINS INVALID ELEMENT SHAPE" and, if i try to run the simulation, the error "ABAQUS SIM DATABASE FILE CANNOT BE OPENED" appears.
I tried to change the mesh geometry as suggested in other topics but nothing changed.

Is this due to the fact that in general this approach can not be used with this type of material with a discontinuity (the fiber) inside?
Actually my real need is to simulate a case with a lot of fibers inside, not just one (see attached picture 2).
Thank you all for the kind attention.